# Correctly manipulating state in reagent

Tags: clojure, clojurescript, reagent

I just learn Reagent in Clojurescript, I am just following some tutorial but maybe I miss something I have this code for the state

```
(defonce app-state (atom {:text "Hello Chestnut!" :click-count 0}))
```

and the rendered view

```
(defn article []
  [:div
   [:div "The atom" [:code "click-count"] " has value : " (:click-count @app-state)]
   [:input {:type "button" :value "Add"
            :on-click #(swap! (:click-count @app-state) inc)}]
   ]
  )
```

I'm trying to increment the state when they button is pressed, but I got this error on the console

> Error: No protocol method ISwap.-swap! defined for type number: 0

Comment: Useful docs: https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/swap!

Comment: I did read it, but thank you :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the atom should be swapped not the :click-count

```
(swap! app-state update :click-count  inc)
```

Comment: Wow.. I was trying (swap! @app-state update-in [:click-count] inc), but doesn't work. Could you tell me, why the @ symbol is not required?

Comment: With @ you only get the current state of the atom, to change the state you must swap the atom itself.

Comment: @MochamadLuckyPradana Your question is more Clojure-specific than Reagent-specific. Try it out in a repl, before doing it in a web-context. It's what makes Clojure(Script) fun :-)

Comment: @Grav : Thank you for the advice. I have a problem with some English language so maybe it will help myself by doing it on the way.. sorry ._.